# Como esperar a que se ejecute la primera llamada antes de ejecutar la segunda en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Tengo una funcion que debe esperar a que primero finalize, para poder ejecutarlo ya que si no lista sera null. Estas se ejecutan por separado y si le dan rapido es posible ejecutar la segunda sin que termine la primera. El codigo es basicamente esto

```
primeraFuncion(){
    falseService.getUsuarios().subscribe(res=>{
        this.lista = res;
    });
}

segundaFuncion(nombre){
    return this.lista.find(c=> c.nombre==nombre);
}
```

Comment: Tienes dos formas:
    - La primera consiste en usar async/await en la función, donde hasta que no se termine esa llamada no sigue el código.
    - La segunda es colocar en el segundo un controlador para que no haga nada mientras la primera siga ejecutándose.

Comment: No se usan promesas en Angular, sino observables

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto

```
primeraFuncion(){
    falseService.getUsuarios().subscribe(res=>{
        this.lista = res;
    }).then((n) => {
      this.secundaFuncion(n.nombre);
     });
 }

segundaFuncion(nombre){
    return this.lista.find(c=> c.nombre==nombre);
}
```

o puedes añadir setTimeout com en ejemplo abajo:

```
primeraFuncion(){
        falseService.getUsuarios().subscribe(res=>{
            this.lista = res;
        }).then((n) => {
          setTimeout(() => {          
          this.secundaFuncion(n.nombre);
          }, 1000)
         });
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Agregando un pipe con un finalize() bastaria para hacer lo que necesitas. Lo que hace el finalize es que luego se ejecuta cuando finaliza todo lo que debe hacer la función de la subscripción.

```
import {finalize} from 'rxjs/operators';

primeraFuncion(){
    falseService.getUsuarios()
    .pipe(finalize( () => this.segundaFuncion()))
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.lista = res;
    });
}

segundaFuncion(nombre){
    return this.lista.find(c => c.nombre == nombre);
}
```

Comment: Y con esta llamada, como puedo realizar el unsubscribe(). Porque si recojo la subscripción "this.clientesSubscription = ..."  no puedo hacer el unsubscribe porque la función finalize no devuelve una suscripción.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de la librería RxJS, en especifico un método que se llama [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin), este te permitirá esperar a que termine la request para utilizar los valores obtenidos en la segunda función que mencionas.